# Linear Algebra Help: Change of Basis Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation of the $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, and suppose there is a vector $v \in V$ such that the set $B = (v, Tv, T^2v,\ldots,T^{n-1}v)$ is a basis of $V$. let $f$ be the characteristic polynomial of $T$

Find the $B$ matrix $[T]_B$ of $T$ in terms of the $B$-coordinates of $T^nv$.

Answer (score 0):

To get each column of $[T]_B$, you find the values of $T$ on the basis and rewrite them as column vectors in the given basis.  Each column vector forms a column of your matrix.  For example, the first column of the matrix is $Tv$, but written in the basis given.  As a row vector this amounts to $(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, because
$$
Tv = 0\cdot v + 1\cdot Tv + 0 \cdot T^2v + \cdots + 0\cdot T^{n-1}v.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) whose last column contains the $B$-coordinates of $T^n v$.